# Why does setting a nullable type to null result in an "Overload resolution ambiguity"?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, null, uppercase

Not Understanding The Null Error Here In KOTLIN

```
 var adam :String? = "i love MY cat"
    adam = null
    print(adam?.uppercase())
```

**So im getting an error at the

```
.uppercase()
```

and its saying

```
** `<html>Overload resolution ambiguity:<br/>public inline fun Char.uppercase(): String defined in kotlin.text<br/>public inline fun String.uppercase(): String defined in kotlin.text ,`
```

**and if i remove the ?** from   print(adam?.uppercase()) its giving me this

```
<html>None of the following function`your text`s can be called with the arguments supplied:<br/>public inline fun Char.uppercase(): String defined in kotlin.text<br/>public inline fun String.uppercase(): String defined in kotlin.text
```

So I'm kinda confused because I'm declaring the var as a nullable String so why is it Giving An Error when I'm saying its null?